# Consolidate/Merge data from TWO IEnumerable Lists into ONE

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have following domain objects in my application:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Supplier
    {
        public virtual string SupplierType { get; set; }
        public virtual string SupplierCode { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual string Rating { get; set; }
        public virtual string WebsiteURL { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CargoSupplier : Supplier
    {
        public virtual IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public virtual string OpeningTime { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClosingTime { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to goto two seperate repositories for getting descriptive content (from database) and pricing (from external webservice) and will have two seperate enumerations populated with data (descriptive content & pricing):

```
IEnumerable<CargoSupplier> cargoSuppliers_Pricing
IEnumerable<CargoSupplier> cargoSuppliers_Content
```

cargoSuppliers_Content will have all fields populated with data EXCEPT `IList<Product>` and cargoSuppliers_Pricing will have `SupplierType, SupplierCode and IList<Product>` fields populated with data. Combination of "SupplierType" amd "SupplierCode" would be the key.

Now I have to merge the content and pricing into one enumeration so I can return `IEnumerable<CargoSupplier> cargoSuppliers` to my Controllers & Views. What is the best way to merge/consolidate these two lists into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want one list that just contains all the items in either list - it sounds like you need to merge individual items. Something like this:

```
var query = from pricing in cargoSuppliers_Pricing
            join content in cargoSuppliers_Content
            on pricing.SupplierCode equals content.SupplierCode
            select new CargoSupplier
            {
                // Copy properties from both objects here
            };
```

Within the "select" part you would take the pricing parts from "pricing" and the content parts from "content", building a CargoSupplier object which has both bits.

Is that what you were after?

Comment: +1 That might be right too. I guess "merge/consolidate" implies he wants something more than Concat.

Comment: Jon, You are correct. I actually need to merge individual items from both lists where I have IList of Product in cargoSuppliers_Pricing. Your soulution worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for Union or am i missing something in the question?

```
var mergedList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

remember to import the `System.Linq` namespace

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

> Concatenates two sequences.

Example:

```
var result = cargoSuppliers_Content.Concat(cargoSuppliers_Pricing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seen the Union() extension method? That should do what your after

```
IEnumerable<CargoSupplier> allCargoSuppliers = cargoSuppliers_Pricing.Union(cargoSuppliers_Content);
```